# GenericMapCellLabelProvider cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, emf, tableviewer, eclipse-databinding

I have been doing some EFM databinding as a part of learning the eclipse modelling framework and one thing that didn't work with window builder was data binding with a `TableViewer` in th sense that it was fine for reading the data, but not for when you wanted to edit the data. so I am following [Tom Shindl's](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2009/06/27/galileo-emf-databinding-part-5/) on how to do it...the trouble is with this piece of code:

```
tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(
                  new GenericMapCellLabelProvider(
                    "{0}", 
                    attributeMap
                  )
                );
```

it says that `GenericMapCellLabelProvider` cannot be resovled...but when I use the `GenericMapCellLabelProvider`, it can be resolved, could someone help explain why this might be? I don't 'think I am missing any dependencies or packages etc..

Comment: The code for `GenericMapCellLabelProvider` is provided in that blog page.

Comment: @greg-449 I know I just saw and feel utterly ridiculous